# Non generic element name accessed generically

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How do I create an xsl method to grab a generic 'list_object_1' or 'list_object_2' and then use the number within the method.  The data getting parsed is unable to be changed.

data to be parsed

```
<list_objects>
  <list_object_1/>
  <list_object_1>
    <list_object_2/>
    ...
  </list_object_1>
```

I thought it would be pretty simple to create a template where name matched the beginning of the element name 'list_object_'.  Is this possible?  All the examples I saw for starts_with used an element name and then parsed the value, not just the element name.

expected template something like

```
<xsl:template match="starts-with(list_object_)>
   <bb>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </bb>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.  This is what you need:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'list_object_')]">
   <bb>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </bb>
</xsl:template>
```